# Room: Storing a NestedList retrieved from JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json, nested-lists, android-room

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get data from a JSON and parse it into a Room Database.
I'm going to use a simple example to show the issue.
There are users who can have multiple subscriptions, every user's subscription has it's own end date.

an example of the JSON could be:

```
[{"customerID":724769,"Subscriptions":[["TV_Sub","1-1-2019"],
["Internet_Sub","2-2-2018"]]},

{"customerID":44444,"Subscriptions":[["Tennis_Sub","1-9-2022"],
["TV_Sub","8-9-2019"]]}]
```

As you can see a customer can have multiple subscriptions with different end dates.

How can I parse this into Room? I know you can use a typeconverter for lists but i have no clue how this will work for what's basically a list in a list. Perhaps @Embedded is a better alternative for this particular problem?

```
   @SerializedName("customerID")
@PrimaryKey
private int customerID;

@SerializedName("Subscriptions")
private List<List<String>> subscriptions = null;
@Ignore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@SerializedName("customerID")
public int getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}

@SerializedName("customerID")
public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
    this.customerID = customerID;
}


public List<List<String>> getSubscriptions() {
    return subscriptions;
}


public void setSubscriptions(List<List<String>> subscriptions) {
    this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
}


public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}


public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
}
```

(Generated by http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

in short want to be able to put the JSON in the database and retrieve the data as shown in the JSON. I need to be able to see which customer is subscribed to what and when the subscription ends.

Comment: Yes !, you should use Embedded for subscription.

Comment: I get the example at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data.html
but how will this know which subscription (TV_Sub) has what end date? (1-1-2019)?

Comment: exactly , use nested object.